# How to Get Video Inside HTML/Javascript Code?

Tags: javascript, html, download

There is a small clip/video on an HTML website that I would like downloaded on my computer.

The clip is in the following code.
Is there any known way to do this?

```
<div class="flourish-embed flourish-bar-chart-race" data-src="visualisation/9727540"><script src="https://public.flourish.studio/resources/embed.js"></script></div>
```

Comment: Can i get the site where you want the clip and which clip you want Cuz I don't see any clip in above html

Comment: @whynotcode yes here is the url where the clip resides - https://public.flourish.studio/visualisation/9727540/

Comment: Just open developer console and go to the "network" tab, find the desired resource and double click it, you can download it there